# Creating a table around a java script code highlighted using minted

Tags: listings, minted, sourcecode

I would like to create a block around javascript code in latex.

I use `minted` package for format highlighting.

Here is my example code:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{minted}

%opening

\begin{document}

\begin{listing}[H]
\begin{minted}{js}
var http = require("http");
    http.createServer(function(request, response) {
        response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
        response.end();
    }).listen(8080);
\end{minted}
\caption{Example of a listing.}
\end{listing}

\end{document}
```

And I get the output as [image: this]

I would like to create a block around the code. Or a table embedding the code.

Any help is really appreciated.

And one more thing, whenever I run the above example on `TexmakerX`, I get an error Package

```
minted Error: You must invoke LaTeX with the -shell-escape flag
```

But when I run it in the cmd, using

```
pdflatex -shell-escape filename
```

it seems to work fine.

How can I make it run in `Texmakerx`?

Comment: Please ask one question at a time. I have answered the part regarding the "block". I am posting a follow-up question regarding how to invoke `-shell-escape` in TeXStudio (the new name of TeXMakerX)

Comment: I have posted the other part of the question here: [How to invoke latex with the -shell-escape flag in TeXMakerX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/99476)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you want to achieve something like this?

[image]

Do you mean you want to put a frame around your code? You have to use the `frame` option. You can choose from the values `none` (the default), `leftline`, `topline`, `bottomline`, `lines`, `single`.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{minted}

%opening

\begin{document}

\begin{listing}[H]
\begin{minted}[frame=single]{js}
var http = require("http");
    http.createServer(function(request, response) {
        response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
        response.end();
    }).listen(8080);
\end{minted}
\caption{Example of a listing.}
\end{listing}

\end{document}
```