# How to invoke latex with the -shell-escape flag in TeXStudio (former TeXMakerX)?

Tags: minted, texstudio, shell-escape

*This is a follow-up question on the post: [Creating a table around a java script code highlighted using minted](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97626/creating-a-table-around-a-java-script-code-highlighted-using-minted/99470#99470) where invoking `-shell-escape` flag in TeXStudio is one of the two questions posted by the OP.*

When running my document in TeXMakerX with `minted` package, I get the error

```
minted Error: You must invoke LaTeX with the `-shell-escape` flag
```

How can I invoke `-shell-escape` in TeXMakerX?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

First of all, TeXMakerX is now [TeXStudio](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/). If you are still running TeXMakerX then it is advised that you upgrade to the latest version of TeXStudio.

[`minted`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/minted) uses `Pygments` of `Python` for the fancy coloring schemes. You need to invoke the `-shell-escape` option in order for LaTeX to allow Pygments to be used.

In TeXStudio, click on the following menu

> Options > Configure TeXStudio > Commands

and change

```
pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

into

```
pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape %.tex
```

### Edit

As mentioned by tohecz in comment, it is better to make a separate command for this in TeXStudio for security reasons. You can do this by clicking

> Options > Configure TeXStudio > Build

and in the **User Commands** box, click <kbd>+Add</kbd> button and add a name for your command in the first cell, say `user:graphviz-pdflatex` and the command `txs:///pdflatex/[--shell-escape]` in the second cell.

[image]

You can then see the command listed in the menu

> Tools > User

[image]
Click on the command to run.

Comment: I would like to remark that it would be better to make a seperate _Command_ for this, so that you don't use --shell-escape when you don't need it. There is a reason why it's not allowed by default (namely, security).

Comment: @tohecz thanks. I have updated my answer accordingly. There is a post somewhere where security threats about the use of `-shell-escape` was discussed but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: I use TexMaker and never heard about TexStudio. I searched about how to upgrade to TexStudio from TexMaker but it seems that I have to download the first one rather than upgrade from the last one, isn't it ?

Comment: @Marine1, TexStudio was a fork of TexMaker. You have to download and install each one separately.

Comment: I still get errors because `Pygments` is not installed. How can I install that in a virutalenv and have TeXStudio use it? I don't want to install it system-wide.

Comment: Is it `-shell-escape` or `--shell-escape`?

Comment: What does `-shell-escape` do exactly? Why is it harmful to always include it in the PdfLatex command?
For some reason, the custom command stopped working for me. It did work before.

Answer (score 40):

TeXstudio also provides a way for documents to define their own build commands directly with "magic" comments.

So you can set the "compile" command to pdflatex augmented with the shell-escape option by including the following comment in the document:

```
% !TeX TXS-program:compile = txs:///pdflatex/[--shell-escape]
```

Or override the entire "pdflatex" command (which is not recommended as it also removes the path information) with

```
% !TeX TXS-program:pdflatex = pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape %.tex
```

Comment: This is a very nice feature, I just tried it, it gives a warning, then after you've accepted to run with shell-espace, it pastes something like this at the top of the document `% !TeX document-id = {423bf6c7-2569-47e5-ab93-e858acbc02fa}`

Answer (score 8):

Another way of doing this, but on a per-document basis, is to use [`arara`](http://cereda.github.com/arara/), which is a tool for automating compilation of (La)TeX files.  `arara` is part of TeX Live 2012, but if you use MikTeX you have to install it manually.

To set up TeXStudio, add a new *User command*, as described in hpesoj626's answer, with the command

```
arara %.tex
```

In your document you have to add one or more rules defining which commands to run, as "magic" comments at the start of the file. To compile with `pdflatex` and shell escape enabled, add

```
% arara: pdflatex: {shell: true}
```

at the beginning of your `.tex` file, and compile with the user command you just created.