# How to enable `shell escape' (or `write18') - Visual Studio Code (Latex Workshop extension)

Tags: pdftex, shell-escape, svg, visual-studio-code

I am working on a .tex file inside Visual Studio Code with the Latex Workshop extension installed. I get following error message when I want Latex to compile .svg files for me, following [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194148/how-to-make-latex-automatically-call-inkscape-to-export-figure-to-pdf-tex)

```
You didn't enable `shell escape' (or `write18')
```

I tried to add '--shell-escape', '-shell-escape', '-enable-write18' to the arguments that are passed to the pdflatex tool in my settings.json with no effect...

```
"latex-workshop.latex.tools": [
    {
        "name": "pdflatex",
        "command": "pdflatex",
        "args": [
            "-synctex=1",
            "-interaction=nonstopmode",
            "-file-line-error",
            "%DOC%",
            "--shell-escape"
        ],
        "env": {}
    },
    {
        "name": "bibtex",
        "command": "bibtex",
        "args": [
            "%DOCFILE%"
        ],
        "env": {}
    }
]
```

Comment: move `--shell-escape` to be before `%DOC%` with the other options like `-file0line-error`

Comment: tried it, the error remains

Comment: well on the commandline you want `pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape myfile.tex`   the filename has to come last. Show the form you used I assume you need a comma between the arguments, looking at your existing setup

Comment: like this?
[magic argument settings](https://abload.de/img/shell-escape17kg3.jpg)

Comment: that image looks wrong you have the filename `diplom.tex` and the placeholder `%DOC%` which I assume expands to the filename again

Comment: How would it be correct? I tried [this](https://abload.de/img/shell-escape2hjja0.jpg) as well

Comment: why are you adding diplom.tex?  Just use the form you post in the question but change the order of the arguments so %DOC% comes last

Comment: haha you are right that makes no sense at all. Yeah [that](https://abload.de/img/shell-escape3n2jue.jpg) was the setup I tried before that, also leading to no solution...

Answer (score 29):

I got it working by modifying **latexmk** task which seems to be invoked by default (auto-update on file edit).

See the [LaTeX Workshop extension FAQ](https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/wiki/FAQ#how-to-pass--shell-escape-to-latexmk) for more info.

1. Open `settings.json` (e.g. `cmd/ctrl + shift + P`, type `Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)` in the command box)
2. Find the entry corresponding to `latex-workshop.latex.tools`. If it's not visible, start typing it as a new entry and VSCode will unhide it.
3. Add `"-shell-escape",` to the args.

Example:

```json
    "latex-workshop.latex.tools": [
        ...
        {
            "name": "latexmk",
            "command": "latexmk",
            "args": [
                "-shell-escape",              // <---- added this line
                "-synctex=1",
                "-interaction=nonstopmode",
                "-file-line-error",
                "-pdf",
                "-outdir=%OUTDIR%",
                "%DOC%"
            ],
            "env": {}
        },
        ...
    ]
```

Comment: A quick way to get to these settings is via **Cmd/Ctrl** + **Shift** + **P** and **Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)**

Comment: Works for me. Thank you!

Comment: Worked for me. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

If the output is created using the AutoBuild feature (build upon file change), the Workshop extension is [using a default recipe](https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/wiki/Compile#auto-build-latex). This is by default the first recipe in latex-workshop.latex.recipes and set to latexmk upon installation.

To change this to pdflatex and have the changes to the pdflatex command in latex-workshop.latex.tools applied when saving the Latex file the next time, you can create a new recipe and move it to the top of latex-workshop.latex.recipes.

```
    {
        "name": "create pdf",
        "tools": [
            "pdflatex"
        ]
    },
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.