# Trying to use VSCode for LaTex instead of Overleaf and moved a project over as a starting point but can't compile

Tags: packages, compiling, vscode

The project works on Overleaf using pdfLaTex but not in VSCode using any of the compilers in the latex workshop extension. I have installed latex via TeX Live.

Previously, I've tried MikTex and using Raspberry Perl combos and so on following relevant guides but none compile on my system. With my current configuration, a sample document could compile so it might be configured correctly but my project starting point (which started with a school template so I don't know if I can just show it) doesn't compile.

Some context to what I think might be the issue:
`main.tex` uses a `setup.sty` called with `\usepackage{setup}`.
Inside of `setup.sty`, on line 1 and 2 is:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{packages}[2020/04/15 Packages]
```

Where the first is underlined with yellow (a warning?):
You have requested package "setup", but the package provides "packages".

And further down in the file:

```
\usepackage{minted} % Includes a lot of languages and styles, info at: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Code_Highlighting_with_minted
```

Which had a red squiggly line in the blank space beneath it.

The error (I think this is the error message):

```
c:/Users/Andreas/LaTex/ELE620 - HW3/main.tex:8: Emergency stop.
<read 3> 
         
l.8 \begin{document}
                    ^^M
c:/Users/Andreas/LaTex/ELE620 - HW3/main.tex:8:  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on main.log.
Latexmk: If appropriate, the -f option can be used to get latexmk
  to try to force complete processing.
Reverting Windows console CPs to (in,out) = (850,850)
Latexmk: Getting log file 'main.log'
Latexmk: Examining 'main.fls'
PWD line not in UTF-8
Latexmk: Examining 'main.log'
Latexmk: Errors, so I did not complete making targets
```

Full log file in pastebin:
https://pastebin.com/t6zZ1EsJ

Does anyone know how I can solve this please?

Comment: as the error message says you need `pdflatex --shell-escape` to use `minted` package (you also need python and pygmentize installed on the machine)

Answer (score 1):

Investigated David Carlisle's response to find out how to add the pdflatex

`--shell-escape`

And found this https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/541385/279366 answer to be a functional fix.

Hope this works for anyone else facing the same issue.