# Sourcecode colorization for more than one programming language

Tags: listings

I want to colorize my source code. I followed this [page](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Source_Code_Listings) and everything works fine.

My problem is that I am using 4 different programming languages: Have I to define the `\lstset{}` [tag](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Source_Code_Listings#Settings) separately for each language or is there a way to declare more than one programming language within its `language` field?

```
\lstset{ %
  %...
  language=java,              % this works only for one programming language. 
                              % How to declare more than one? 
                              % Or have I to declare \lstset{} for each PL? 
  %...
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ideally one should define a new `listings` environment for each of the languages. That is, create a listing for `python`, one for `java`, one for `c` and one for `php`. For each of these, we use `\lstnewenvironment`:

```
\lstnewenvironment{python}
  {\lstset{language=python,...}}
  {}
\lstnewenvironment{java}
  {\lstset{language=java,...}}
  {}
\lstnewenvironment{clang}
  {\lstset{language=c,...}}
  {}
\lstnewenvironment{php}
  {\lstset{language=php,...}}
  {}
```

where `...` denotes other tailored settings specific to the language in question. For more detail on this, see the section **5.14 Environments** of the [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf).

The above now allows you to use (say)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstnewenvironment{python}
  {\lstset{language=python}}
  {}

\begin{document}

\begin{python}
print "This line will be printed."
\end{python}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you sir. One last thing if I may: you said *ideally*: does this mean it is impossible to declare the 4 languages within the field `language`? To be honest, I tried several combinations but no one worked, I got errors.

Comment: @Begueradj: Ideally refers to the fact that your LaTeX code will match the syntax that you're trying to achieve. It's more clear to write python code inside a `python` environment than it would be to write it in a standard `listings` environment where you've `\lstset{...}` the language in the preamble. You'd have to switch between languages otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

Of course there also exists a solution with `minted`

Therefor you can define different code environments which is pretty easy with `minted`

```
\usepackage{minted}
\usemintedstyle{vs}

\newminted{kotlin}{%
    breakbytoken,%
    breaklines,%
    autogobble,%
    frame=lines,%
    label=Kotlin,%
    framesep=2\fboxsep%
}

\newminted{mysql}{%
    breakbytoken,%
    breaklines,%
    autogobble,%
    label=SQL,%
}
```

For every environment you are able to define different parameters.

To use your defined environments one uses `\begin{language+'code'}`

```
\begin{kotlincode}
        data class Customer(val name: String, val email: String, val company: String)
\end{kotlincode}
```

The full example would look like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}
\usemintedstyle{vs}

\newminted{kotlin}{%
    breakbytoken,%
    breaklines,%
    autogobble,%
    frame=lines,%
    label=Kotlin,%
    framesep=2\fboxsep%
}

\newminted{mysql}{%
    breakbytoken,%
    breaklines,%
    autogobble,%
    label=SQL,%
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{kotlincode}
            data class Customer(val name: String, val email: String, val company: String)
    \end{kotlincode}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Indeed, that would be a perfect solution but that package does not work on my OS. Thank you very much for the effort and the idea though.

Comment: I assume you don't have `pygments` installed? This works on every OS but requires python

Comment: I installed `pygments` and did a [few settings](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99475/how-to-invoke-latex-with-the-shell-escape-flag-in-texmakerx). Now `minted` works perfectly fine. Thank you very much for the help.