# How do I "invoke LaTeX" with flags when using laTeXTools in Sublime Text?

Tags: shell-escape, latextools

I'm using LaTeXTools for Sublime Text 3, and trying to use the `minted` package. I get the following error:

> Package minted Error: You must invoke LaTeX with the -shell-escape
>   flag. [\usepackage]

How do I "invoke LaTeX" with flags when using laTeXTools? There is a similar question with an answer here: [How to invoke latex with the -shell-escape flag in TeXMakerX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99475/how-to-invoke-latex-with-the-shell-escape-flag-in-texmakerx)

But that answer is for TeXstudio. And I don't know how that translates to Sublime Text 3 on Windows 10

Comment: According to [the documentation of LaTeXTools](https://latextools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings/#builder-settings) this can be done by editing the settings file.

Comment: @leandriis Can you make an answer from your comment. IMHO, it could be useful to have an answer, that describes what to change and how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the first comment above, you can add flags to the LaTeXTools user settings. Specifically, you need to configure the builder. To do this

```
1. Go to preferences,
2. Go packages settings
3. Choose LaTeXTools
4. Go to user settings
5. Add the options tuple to "builder_settings"


"builder_settings" : {
    "options": ["--shell-escape"],
     ....
 }
```

You can find more information here: https://latextools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings/#builder-settings