# MWE for Norwegian index with Xindy, anyone?

Tags: indexing, xindy

I would like to make a Norwegian index for a book. Is there a MWE 
which can help me?

Comment: I cannot compile these. Perhaps it is because I use \AE, \O, \AA for the Norwegian letters.

Comment: If you are using commands like `\AE` rather than using UTF-8 characters, you need to add a merge rule for each of those commands. For example `(merge-rule "\\AE *" "Æ" :eregexp :again)`

Answer (score 3):

Run with shell escape enabled or run

```
xindy -M texindy -L norwegian -C utf8 <filename>.idx
```

after a LaTeX run.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[norsk]{babel}

\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}

\makeindex[options=-M texindy -L norwegian -C utf8]

\begin{document}

xyz

\index{henne}
\index{selv}
\index{denne}
\index{før}
\index{slik}
\index{gikk}
\index{hva}
\index{igjen}
\index{fikk}
\index{man}
\index{alt}
\index{mange}
\index{ingen}
\index{får}
\index{oss}
\index{hvor}
\index{under}
\index{siden}
\index{hele}
\index{dag}
\index{gang}
\index{sammen}
\index{ned}
\index{ångstrom}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What does "shell escape enabled" mean?

Comment: It compiled, but ångstrøm was ranked first. I did not follow the instruction on having shell escape enabled, as I do not understand it.

Comment: @FrodeBjørdal It means run `pdflatex --shell-escape file.tex` instead of `pdflatex file.tex`.   With that I get ångstrøm in the correct place.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I use Texstudio, and I do not see how to run either of these.

Comment: @FrodeBjørdal `pdflatex` without `shell-escape` is likely what you're using to generate the PDF now.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/99601/ for one way of activating `shell-escape` for a document.

Comment: @Torbjørn T. I tried % !TeX TXS-program:compile = txs:///pdflatex/[--shell-escape] in the preamble, but this did not alter the ranking and ångstrøm is still first.

Comment: @FrodeBjørdal I added `% !TeX TXS-program:compile = txs:///pdflatex/[--shell-escape]` before `\documentclass`, and when hitting F6, I got a question if I would allow changing the build command, which I agreed to, and then it worked fine. I don't really use TeXstudio, so I'm not that familiar with it, and can't say why it wouldn't work for you (unless you have an older version perhaps).

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thanks, but even this did not work for me, unfortunately.