# Gnuplottex not working in TeXstudio

Tags: gnuplottex

I wanted to use `gnuplottex` to create my plots directly in TeXstudio but so far I didn't get any results. When I use the following I get

```
Conversion of document-gnuplottex-fig1.gnuplot failed.
Please convert document-gnuplottex-fig1.gnuplot manually.
```

and

```
Der Befehl "gnuplot" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder konnte nicht gefunden werden.
```

which translates to "The command "gnuplot" is mistyped or couldn't be found".

Also, `-shell-escape` is enabled.

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{lmodern} 

\usepackage[miktex]{gnuplottex}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}

\usepackage{microtype} 

\begin{document}
\begin{gnuplot}
    set xrange [-10:10]
    yet yrange [-10:10]
    f(x) = x**2 + 5*x
    plot f(x)
\end{gnuplot}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You need to enable `shell-escape`, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99475/how-to-invoke-latex-with-the-shell-escape-flag-in-texmakerx (edit: sorry, didn't see you had enabled it). With that, fixing the typo in `set yrange`, and removing `[miktex]` (because I don't use MikTeX), it works fine.

Comment: It still didn't work for me. I just opened the document-gnuplottex-fig1.gnuplot in Gnuplot and after recompiling my document I could see a graph. The problem now is that it looks like this: https://i.imgur.com/ESJWA1m.png

Comment: There is a second cutoff graph which shouldn't be there.

Comment: Try deleting all the gnuplot-generated files, and recompiling.

Comment: I deleted all the gnuplot files and every other file but the .tex file and tried recompiling. I still didn't get anything. Tried updating the packages with MiKTeX Update and compiling again but that didn't help either.

Answer (score 1):

Reinstalling Gnuplot and checking "Add application directory to your PATH environment variable" during the installation solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the compilation command:

> pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -shell-escape -enable-write18
>   -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex

... and fixed   typography it should work. Alternatively you could try this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[unit vector ratio*=1 1 1,ymin=-10,ymax=10,xmin=-10,xmax=10]
\addplot[domain=-10:10,no markers,red,ultra thick] gnuplot{x**2 + 5*x};
\addlegendentry{$f(x)$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Note:`set size ratio -1` set the same ratio in all axis directions.

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[miktex]{gnuplottex}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}


\begin{document}
\begin{gnuplot}
    set size ratio -1
    set xrange [-10:10]
    set yrange [-10:10]
    f(x) = x**2 + 5*x
    plot f(x)
\end{gnuplot}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[unit vector ratio*=1 1 1,ymin=-10,ymax=10,xmin=-10,xmax=10]
\addplot[domain=-10:10,no markers,red,ultra thick] gnuplot{x**2 + 5*x};
\addlegendentry{$f(x)$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I did exactly what you said. I edited my compilation command, copy pasted your code and I still get an error. As long as I don't open the produced .gnuplot file in Gnuplot and compile again I don't get a plot.

Comment: Have you checked all packages? Installed? For example `gnuplottex`?

Comment: When I first tried using those packages it prompted me to install them. Just checked them in the MiKTeX package manager. They are installed. Edit: I think there is a problem with my -shell-escape command. It just creates a "document-gnuplottex-fig1.gnuplot" file. There is no "document-gnuplottex-fig1.tex" file as long as I don't create it myself by opening the former file in Gnuplot.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem for a long time. After download the latest version of gnuplot, enabling shell escape, trying to write [miktex] in the \usepackage command, I finally found the solution (for me which I didn't find anywhere else). 
I was compiling a tex file which contains blanks in its name. I just replaces them by "_", and the errors go away by magic. I plot the graph of sin(x) with this :

\begin{gnuplot}
plot sin(x)
\end{gnuplot}

Hope I rescue some people from wasting days to find a solution about how to plot a graph in LaTeX.

Comment: Welcome to TEXSE, Please clarify how this is an answer to the question.