# TeXstudio, no preview pdf file after compiling using User Commands

Tags: texstudio, minted, viewers

I was trying to use package minted to insert Python code in my document and now succeeded in compiling and could generate the correct PDF file. I followed [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99475/how-to-invoke-latex-with-the-shell-escape-flag-in-texmakerx) which said it's better to create your own user command contained

```
pdflatex -shell-escape -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

But using this command to compile will not pop up the internal pdfviewer as using F5 to compile.

I tried goto

> Options > Configure TeXStudio > Commands

and changed

```
pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

into

```
pdflatex -shell-escape -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

then compiled through F5 again. This time it compiled correct and pop up the internal pdfviewer.

How can I still using user command but have internal pdfviewer at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

Under `Configure TeXstudio -> Build -> User commands`, you can 'stack' the commands with the `|` character, so something like:

```
pdflatex --shell-escape -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex | txs:///view-pdf
```

should work. (see red box)

[image]

Alternatively, you can click the 'Spanner' icon (blue box in pic) to configure the Quick build command, in which you can add TXS-specific commands to the list, including `view-pdf`:

[image: quickbuild]

Comment: I did what you showed in the image, but it did't work. It still compiled succeeded but no viewer pop up.

Comment: @Adam_Hu Take screenshots of what you have on your TXS settings. Specifically the equivalent of the two windows shown in my answer. And add it into your question in an edit.

Comment: @Adam_Hu Also, what pdf viewer are you using -- internal or external? What TeXstudio version are you using?