# TeXstudio, no preview pdf file after compiling with User Commands

Tags: xetex, texstudio

I have similar problem as the person who asked this question
([TeXstudio, no preview pdf file after compiling using User Commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/417112/texstudio-no-preview-pdf-file-after-compiling-using-user-commands)), which was not solved.

Since I use package minted to insert Python code in my document, I use this user command to compile my code:

```
xelatex -8bit -shell-escape -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex | txs:///view-pdf
```

With this command, I generate the correct pdf file, but the problem is that the internal pdf viewer will not pop up.

How can I use user command and have internal pdfviewer at the same time?

Comment: Which part of the manual includes "should just be single commands (i.e. do not use | there)" ? did not answer the linked question Note this is a rhetorical question, since that is exactly what the manual does imply. This should be a separately / independently worded question. Avoid suggesting useless non working methods might be fixed. There is an answer to your question just not down that route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure a new user command has ONE word (not a duplicate of any other, especially the first word)

So lets build XLView we note from the manual and other sources that we should have one default XeLaTeX command (default) and another which exposes us to external control via shell-escape.

Thus we need to build XLShell first
so enter in this case your desired user command

> xelatex -8bit -shell-escape -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex

Now we can chain with the internal viewer

so add the user command XLView

[image]