# Package minted Error: You must invoke LaTeX with the -shell-escape flag. \begin

Tags: xetex

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
\begin{minted}{c}
int main() {
printf("hello, world");
return 0;
}
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: as the message says, you need to use `pdflatex --shell-escape document` not `pdflatex document` to allow pdftex to call pygmentize to style the code.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99475/how-to-invoke-latex-with-the-shell-escape-flag-in-texmakerx for instructions how to do this in TeXstudio.

Comment: This question is already answered. Would you please check it [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99475/how-to-invoke-latex-with-the-shell-escape-flag-in-texstudio-former-texmakerx)?