# Library graphs - mixture between layered layout and tree - How to do?

Tags: graphs, trees

the creation of a graph with some specific attributes is for me not possible. Maybe you have some helpfully ideas how to realize?!

The attributes of the graphs in 1. and 2. have to be "mixed", while in 3. the style of the link connection between parent and outgoing chain (child) is a nice to have option.

1.
To save space the "layered layout" is preferred but without the labyrinthine chain structure, see lower figure (B). For example, instead of the structure

```
1-3 -> 5-1 (same line)
    -> 1-4 (new line)
```

it has to look like

```
1-3 -> 1-4 (same line)
    -> 5-1 (new line)
```

2.
From the parent chain several child chains can be branched. All chain links from the parent chain have to be in the same line, like in the upper figure (A).

3.
The initial link of each outgoing chain (child with the attributes [>red, bend right, very thick]) must be a rectangle instead of a straight line.

Thank you for your help!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{layered}


\begin{document}
    \tikz [
    rotate=90,
    ]
    \graph [
    ]{
        "1-1" -> {
            "1-2" -> "1-3" ->{
                "1-4" ->"1-5"->{
                    "1-6",
                    "2-1"[>red, bend right, very thick]
                    ->"2-2"->{
                        "2-3",
                        "4-1"[>red, bend right, very thick]
                    },
                },
                "5-1"[>red, bend right, very thick]
                ->"5-2"->"5-3"->"5-4"
            },
            "3-1"[>red, bend right, very thick]
            ->"3-2"->"3-3"->"3-4"->"3-5"->"3-6"->"3-7"->"3-8"->"3-9"->"3-10"->"3-11"->"3-12"
        }
    };

    \hspace{2cm}

    \tikz [
    layered layout,
    rotate=90
    ]
    \graph [
    ]{
        "1-1" -> {
            "1-2" -> "1-3" ->{
                "1-4" ->"1-5"->{
                    "1-6",
                    "2-1"[>red, bend right, very thick]
                    ->"2-2"->{
                        "2-3",
                        "4-1"[>red, bend right, very thick]
                    },
                },
                "5-1"[>red, bend right, very thick]
                ->"5-2"->"5-3"->"5-4"
            },
            "3-1"[>red, bend right, very thick]
            ->"3-2"->"3-3"->"3-4"->"3-5"->"3-6"->"3-7"->"3-8"->"3-9"->"3-10"->"3-11"->"3-12"
        }
    };
\end{document}
```

Here the upper code as an figure:
[image: upper (A) and lower (A) example]

The idea is to obtain a graph that looks like:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please add an screenshot of your result to your question and mark there what you want to change?

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The Stack Exchange staff can [merge them together for you](//tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Comment: thx. for the hint with the two separated accounts. Now, it should be fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of the *dot* language with the program [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) together with the [dot2tex](https://dot2tex.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package (to include the *dot* figure in LaTeX) was helpful to get the wished result. Benefits of dot is a simpler writing of the graph, see code and figure example.

On the other hand, the squared edge is not always drawn as it should be, see [Graphviz edge between nodes wrong drawn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58021868/graphviz-edge-between-nodes-wrong-drawn#).

For everyone how need squared edges to connect single notes can have a look to the threat: [Can DOT produce a more structured graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55402109/can-dot-produce-a-more-structured-graph/55403592).

A problem that can occur by usage of *dot2tex* during PDF compilation (it is often the [--shell-escape-flag](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99475/how-to-invoke-latex-with-the-shell-escape-flag-in-texstudio-former-texmakerx) problem). Have a look to the last link to find a solution if you use TexStudio.

Here are the example code and the corresponding figure:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[debug]{dot2texi}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\begin{document}
    \begin{dot2tex}[]
    digraph {
        rankdir=LR;
        pencolor=transparent;
        graph [splines=ortho];
        subgraph cluster1{
1->2->3->4->5;
}
subgraph cluster2 {
6->7->8->9->10.1;
}
subgraph cluster3 {
11->12->13->14->15;
}
subgraph cluster4 {
16->17->18->19->20;
}
subgraph cluster5 {
21->22->23->24->25
}
1->11;
3->21;
5->6;
1 [label="1-1"];
7->16;
}
    \end{dot2tex}
\end{document}
```

[image: Ortho graph with subclusters]