# trouble with packages dsfont and minted with using vimtex

Tags: minted, vim, compilation-error, vim-latex

I'm trying to use vim / nvim as text editor in a (long) .tex file containing both `minted` and `dsfont` package. Here is an example:

```
% !TeX document-id = {f2e9e8a7-1386-4a73-9989-55350ce6c529}
% !TeX TXS-program:compile = txs:///xelatex/[--shell-escape]
%\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{book}
\documentclass{scrreprt}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
%\usepackage{pmboxdraw}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, float, framed, geometry, listings, lmodern, mathtools,multirow,parskip, paralist,pgfplots, ragged2e,setspace,tcolorbox, threeparttable, upquote, url, tikz, enumitem}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{dsfont} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabto}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{mypink1}{RGB}{0, 170, 0}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\rfoot{Page \thepage}
\usepackage[LGR]{fontenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta,
    citecolor=mypink1,      
    urlcolor=cyan,
}
\geometry{
    a4paper,
    total={170mm,257mm},
    left=20mm,
    top=20mm,
}
\usepackage{caption}
%\usepackage{calrsfs}
%\DeclareMathAlphabet{\pazocal}{OMS}{zplm}{m}{n}
\begin{document}
blabla
\begin{minted}{Python}
    print(“Hello world”)
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

I can compile the document with both Texstudio and pdflatex in the terminal without problems. However trying to view it with `:LLPStartPreview` gives me a `Failed to compile` message and a the following message in the `.log` file:

```
l.13 \usepackage
                {dsfont}
Pass the -shell-escape flag to LaTeX. Refer to the minted.sty documentation for
 more information.
```

I had a look at the minted doc but couldn't find the solution to the problem
What am I doing wrong?

**Edit1**

After having checked [this other answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99475/how-to-invoke-latex-with-the-shell-escape-flag-in-texstudio-former-texmakerx), I also tried to replace the line

```
% !TeX TXS-program:compile = txs:///xelatex/[--shell-escape]
```

by

```
% !TeX TXS-program:compile = txs:///pdflatex/[--shell-escape]
```

and

```
% !TeX TXS-program:pdflatex = pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape %.tex
```

but it didn't solve the problem

**Edit 2**
I try to insert (in `.vimrc` file)

```
let g:vimtex_compiler_latexmk.options += ['-shell-escape']
let g:vimtex_compiler_method = 'latexmk'
```

and

```
let g:vimtex_compiler_latexmk.options += ['-shell-escape']
let g:vimtex_compiler_method = 'latexmk'
```

but it didn't solve the problem

**Edit 3**
I tried (sequentially) to add the following command in the `.vimrc` file but it didn't solve the problem:

- `let g:livepreview_engine = 'evince' . [-shell-escape]`
- `let g:livepreview_engine = 'evince' . ['-shell-escape']`
- `let g:livepreview_engine = 'evince' . '[-shell-escape]'`
- `let g:livepreview_engine =. ' -shell-escape'`

**Edit 4**
I tried also to add the following line in my `.vimrc` without success
`let g:livepreview_engine = 'pdflatex' . '[-shell-escape]'`

The problem didn't appear when I used `:LLPStartPreview` with the following code:
(where the following lines where commented out):

```
...
\usepackage{minted}
...
\begin{minted}{Python}
    print(“Hello world”)
\end{minted}
```

```
% !TeX document-id = {f2e9e8a7-1386-4a73-9989-55350ce6c529}
% !TeX TXS-program:pdflatex = pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape %.tex
%\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{book}
\documentclass{scrreprt}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
%\usepackage{pmboxdraw}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, float, framed, geometry, listings, lmodern, mathtools,multirow,parskip, paralist,pgfplots, ragged2e,setspace,tcolorbox, threeparttable, upquote, url, tikz, enumitem}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{xurl}
%\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{dsfont} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabto}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{mypink1}{RGB}{0, 170, 0}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\rfoot{Page \thepage}
\usepackage[LGR]{fontenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta,
    citecolor=mypink1,      
    urlcolor=cyan,
}
\geometry{
    a4paper,
    total={170mm,257mm},
    left=20mm,
    top=20mm,
}
\usepackage{caption}
%\usepackage{calrsfs}
%\DeclareMathAlphabet{\pazocal}{OMS}{zplm}{m}{n}
\begin{document}
blabla
%\begin{minted}{Python}
%   print(“Hello world”)
%\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `dsfont` has nothing to do with this. You need to enable shell-escape for processing documents relying on `minted`. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/99475/4427

Comment: Thank you for your comment @egreg. I checked the linked and tried to modify the .tex file accordingly but it didn't solve the problem (when trying to use specificall :LLPStartPreview although it works in texstudio). I edited the question accordingly

Comment: `let g:livepreview_engine = 'evince' . [-shell-escape]` requires the pdf**engine**, ie. something like latexmk or pdflatex, **not** evince. Evince is a pdf**viewer**

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** After [DG' pointed out a major misconception I had](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/526689/trouble-with-packages-dsfont-and-minted-with-using-vimtex/526703#comment1332155_526703) it looks like what has to be altered is not the compilation route of `vimtex` but the route of `vim-latex-live-preview`. According to its README, the compilation can be controlled by setting `g:livepreview_engine`. To add the `-shell-escape` option to it one could do

```
:let g:livepreview_engine .= ' -shell-escape'
```

Unfortunately I don't use `vim-latex-live-preview` so can't test this.

---

## Original answer

**Note:** I don't use `vimtex` personally, so I can't verify whether the following really works. But I include the way one could find the information necessary for all this and think that it should work (it's what I'd try).

`vimtex` is not TeXstudio and doesn't parse for TeXstudio's magic comments, afaik.

If in `vim` (or `nvim` for what it's worth) you can get help on most things by typing `:help <thing>` and hitting enter. In particular you can get help about `vimtex` by typing `:help vimtex`. There you'll find information on the used compilation method and how to customize it. (For others who don't have `vimtex` installed, the help file can be found [here](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/blob/master/doc/vimtex.txt))

By default `vimtex` uses `latexmk`. You should/could change the options passed to `latexmk` by changing the `g:vimtex_compiler_latexmk` dictionary, more specifically change the `options` field of that dictionary. For that you can type the following in normal mode:

```
:let g:vimtex_compiler_latexmk.options += ['-shell-escape']
```

Hit enter. Now for the current vim session you'll compile with `-shell-escape` allowed and `minted` should work out.

Alternatively you could also configure `vimtex` to use another compile route. `vimtex` supports:

- `latexmk`
- `latexrun`
- `tectonic`
- `arara`

You can choose among these by setting `g:vimtex_compiler_method` like so (example uses `arara`):

```
:let g:vimtex_compiler_method = 'arara'
```

The example above uses `arara` because you can configure `arara` by using magic comments, but I'm no expert for `arara` either, so either search for information about it or consult its [pretty documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/arara).

Comment: many thanks for your answer @Skillmonlikestopanswers.xyz. I tried to modify the `.vimrc` file accordingly (see Edit 2 in my question) but it didn't solve the problem

Comment: @ecjb have you resourced your rc? Also did you insert that *after* `vimtex` gets loaded? As an aside, I don't recommend generally allowing `-shell-escape` in your `.vimrc` for every LaTeX project and would only allow that per session with the code above! Did you try using that with an already started vim, like suggested in my answer? As I said, I can't test this at all, so I'm a bit in the dark here and can only guess.

Comment: FWIW: The OP *claims* to be unsing `vimtex` but the command `LLPStartPreview` is provided by [`vim-latex-live-preview`](https://github.com/xuhdev/vim-latex-live-preview), which is configured with: `let g:livepreview_engine = 'your_engine' . ' [options]'
`

Comment: @Skillmonlikestopanswers.xyz: So I removed the `let g:vimtex_compiler_latexmk.options += ['-shell-escape']` as you advised and tried to enter it during the session. That unfortunately didn't help. By "resource my rc", do you mean restart the terminal (I'm on MacOS) ==> If yes, I restarted the terminal after editing the `.vimrc` but it didn't solve the probelm. Finally "after `vimtex` gets loaded: you mean after loading a .tex file with vim? ==> if yes, that didn't solve the problem. But many thanks for your comments!

Comment: Maybe also relevant: https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/issues/305

Comment: many thanks for your comment @DG. So in my `.vimrc` file there is already currently a line `let g:livepreview_previewer = 'evince'`. Shall I add something?

Comment: @DG' thanks, that might explain a lot!

Comment: @ecjb from the README of the link to vim-latex-live-preview it looks like you have to alter the variable `g:livepreview_engine`, you could do something like `:let g:livepreview_engine .= ' -shell-escape'` with an already running vim which has already loaded the tex file.

Comment: Thanks again for the support @Skillmonlikestopanswers.xyz. I tried to implement your advice and edited the question accordingly, but it unfortunately still didn't work

Comment: what I should also add, is that. There are no problem with other .tex file

Comment: @ecjb Read here: https://github.com/xuhdev/vim-latex-live-preview