# Python not found when using tcolorbox with minted

Tags: tcolorbox, minted, python

I'm new to LaTeX and I want to use it for my homeworks.

Before asking help here, I opened a issue on [`minted`'s github](https://github.com/gpoore/minted/issues/285), and the guy suggested to go here. So here is my problem :

I'm trying to use `tcolorbox` with `minted`,

Here is a test code :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{minted}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcblisting}{minted language=java, listing only}
    String s = "abc";
\end{tcblisting}
\end{document}
```

It don't want to compile it, because it doesn't find Python. I have a full portable installation of MiKTeX, VS Code (LaTeX Workshop) and of Python 3.8

By the way, I tried minted without `tcolorbox` and it worked perfectly.

Test code :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}
\begin{minted}{java}
  String s = "abc";
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

Here is compilation's log of `tcolorbox` + `minted` tex file : [test.log](https://hastebin.com/qodajenoye.coffeescript)

And compilation's log of minted tex file : [test_2.log](https://hastebin.com/esecosayaj.yaml)

Comment: Did you compile your document with `-shell-escape` flag enabled? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99475/how-to-invoke-latex-with-the-shell-escape-flag-in-texstudio-former-texmakerx/99476

Comment: Yes, I compiled with ```-shell-escape``` flag and I tried ```--enable-write18``` too

Comment: tcolorbox activates the autogobble option, and you seem to have problems with the python code this calls. What happens in the example without tcolorbox if you add the option  `\begin{minted}[autogobble]{java}`?

Comment: I added ```\begin{minted}[autogobble]{java}``` and checked the output and I found the same error on my problem : ```r:\LaTeX\Cours\test>set  /p x= 0<nul: 1>>test.aex 
 (R:\LaTeX\MiKTeX\texmfs\install\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-xetex.def) (test.aux) (R:\LaTeX\MiKTeX\texmfs\install\tex/latex/base\ts1cmr.fd) (_minted-test/default-pyg-prefix.pygstyle) (_minted-test/default.pygstyle)Python est introuvable. Ex�cutez sans argument pour proc�der � l (_minted-test/EA71F2074989B1673C1B5B01EDA200D266859B547044602182DB085823A77966.pygtex) [1] (test.aux)```, but the compilation is working.

Comment: and what happens if you call `python --help` on a command line? Is it found?

Comment: It's a portable installation, so it's not found but I added a custom PATH env in VS Code (with a batch file) and LaTeX Workshop (settings.json from VS Code)

Comment: I disabled autogobble by adding ``` minted options={autogobble=false,linenos,breaklines}``` and now it works... What is autogobble ?

Comment: Hi I'm muzimuzhi in GitHub. What do you get by running `xelatex --shell-escape test.tex` with `test.tex` containing `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\write18{python --version}
\end{document}`?

Comment: Hi, I probably found the problem.

It's probably from Windows with App Execution Aliases, when you type python in a CMD, it redirect to the Windows Store.

By the way, I tried your code and it give log but not the Python version

EDIT : My first code is still not working on Github

Comment: Can you see the python version in standard output? With `xelatex --shell-escape test.tex` used, It will read sth like `(/usr/local/texlive/2020basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd) [1Python 2.7.16
] (./test.aux) )`.

Comment: I got nothing. 

[Standard output](https://hastebin.com/rusanubopa.yaml) 

[Full log](https://hastebin.com/pavuheyuce.yaml)

Comment: The `\write` is not executed, because there is no page shipout. Try this one: `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
text\write18{python --version}text
\end{document}`.

Comment: It show the Python version now. I will retry my first code

Comment: The first code on GitHub works now! Thank you for your help

Comment: You can do more tests to trace down to the exact change that helps/matters, then post it here as an answer and there in GitHub.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix :

- Add Python to PATH
- Go to Settings, App and Features, Execution aliases
- Disable Python
- Restart your PC

For checking if it's working :

```
\documentclass{article} 
\begin{document} 
text
\write18{python --version}
text 
\end{document}
```

Thanks to everyone.