# Latex with VSCode

Tags: luatex, vscode

Anyone using VSCode to work with Latex?
I try create a `.latexmkrc` with this content:

```
$pdflatex='lualatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode  -shell-escape';
```

But always have this error:

```
main.tex (line 7)
Package minted Error: You must have `pygmentize' installed to use this package. (\begin{document} ...)
```

But already have Pygments installed.
Anyone can help me?

Comment: How many versions of Python do you have on your computer? This looks like that one version Python without `pygments` installed is used.

Comment: I using pyenv on my mac to override the default version, but already try pip2 and pip3 to install pygments and all have installed

Comment: Can you try the little snippet in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/576235/6880)?

Comment: The Pygments already work, the problem is the VSCode build using Lualatex now.
Trying find a new way to build with Lualatex