# ! Package minted Error: You must have `pygmentize' installed to use this packag e. \begin{document}

Tags: texstudio, pygments

How to fix this error please?

```
! Package minted Error: You must have `pygmentize' installed to use this packag
e.\begin{document}
```

I applied the answer of hpesoj626 in this question, but the same problem!

[enter link description here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99475/how-to-invoke-latex-with-the-shell-escape-flag-in-texstudio-former-texmakerx)

Comment: pygments is a python package not a tex one, you must install it and make it in your path so that the  `pygmentize` command is available.

Comment: So why I got on this error when use Textstudio ?

Comment: pygmentize is not in the path of the shell used by your texstudio, that will be fixable but I don't use that editor

Comment: The same thing with TexMake !!

Comment: have you installed pyments? can you type `pygmentize -V` in a command window? (it should say something like `Pygments version 2.10.0, (c) 2006-2021 by Georg Brandl, Matthäus Chajdas and contributors`

Comment: Like this? C:\Users\lab>pygmentize -V
'pygmentize' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: So if you have not installed pygments (which is a python program) then obviously latex can not use it.

Comment: If you are not happy to install pythonand python libraries such as pygments, use `listings` not `minted` that is all written in tex so needs no extra installation

Comment: I have python on my laptop, but how can I use listings or minted, please?

Comment: start with listings, it's easier, there are literally thousands of examples on this site https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/listings